# FeatureToggle React Jest - TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, featuretoggle

I've got a component that uses `featuretoggle-react` to render some stuff. For example:

```
import { On, FeatureToggle } from "featuretoggle-react";

const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <FeatureToggle feature="my_feature">
            <On>
                // render whatever
            </On>
        </FeatureToggle>
    )
}
```

I'm now creating tests using `Jest` for `MyComponent`. An example is as follows:

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { On, FeatureToggle } from "featuretoggle-react";
import { store } from "stores";

test("load my component", async () => {
  const mockComponent = () => <div></div>;
  jest.mock("featuretoggle-react", () => mockComponent);
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FeatureToggle feature="my_feature"> // error is signaled here
        <On>
          <MyComponent />
        </On>
      </FeatureToggle>
    </Provider>
  );

  // assert some stuff but there is an error returning above
});
```

When I run the above test, I get the resultant error as:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

If I comment out the `<FeatureToggle feature="my_feature">` from within `MyComponent` (as well as in the test), my tests run successfully, which is why I'm inclined to believe that it is an error thrown because of `<FeatureToggle />`

I have tried to mock it using

```
const mockComponent = () => <div></div>;
jest.mock("featuretoggle-react", () => mockComponent);
```

but I still get the same error.

**EDIT:** even if I don't mock `featuretoggle-react`, I still get the same error.

Comment: Why are you trying to mock `featuretoggle-react` module? Don't mock it, just render it and check that the rendered content is as expected

Comment: Even if I don't mock it, I still get the same error. Could you show me what you mean?